# grab n letter words don't count apostrophes regex

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to learn regex in R more deeply.  I gave myself what I thought was an easy task that I can't figure out.  I want to extract all 4 letter words.  In these four letter words I want to ignore (don't count) apostrophes.  I can do this without regex but want a regex solution.  Here's a MWE and what I've tried:

```
text.var <- "This Jon's dogs' 'bout there in Mike's re'y word."
pattern <- "\\b[A-Za-z]{4}\\b(?!')"
pattern <- "\\b[A-Za-z]{4}\\b|\\b[A-Za-z']{5}\\b"

regmatches(text.var, gregexpr(pattern, text.var, perl = TRUE))
```

** Desired output:**

```
[[1]]
[1] "This"  "Jon's"  "dogs'"  "'bout"  "word"
```

I thought the second pattern would work but it grabs words containing 5 characters as well.

Comment: the second pattern is *allowed* to contain apostrophes but not *required* to do so ...

Comment: @Ben yeah I understand why but not how to make it say you must contain one apostrophe.  I tried the following for that: `"\\b'*([A-Za-z]{4}\\'*)\\'*\\b"` but it doesn't return the apostrophes.

Comment: And I wouldn't use \b, as it'll exclude (will start matching after/before) the single quotes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a good challenging question and here is a tricky answer.

```
> x  <- "This Jon's dogs' 'bout there in Mike's re'y word."
> re <- "(?i)('?[a-z]){5,}(*SKIP)(?!)|('?[a-z]){4}'?"
> regmatches(x, gregexpr(re, x, perl=T))[[1]]
## [1] "This"  "Jon's" "dogs'" "'bout" "word"
```

**Explanation**:

The idea is to **skip** any word patterns that consist of 5 or more letter characters and an optional apostrophe.

On the left side of the alternation operator we match the subpattern we do not want.
Making it fail and forcing the regular expression engine to not retry the substring using backtracking control. As explained below:

```
(*SKIP) # advances to the position in the string where (*SKIP) was 
        # encountered signifying that what was matched leading up 
        # to cannot be part of the match

(?!)    # equivalent to (*FAIL), causes matching failure, 
        # forcing backtracking to occur
```

The right side of the alternation operator matches what we want...

### Additional Explanation:

- Essentially, in simple terms you are using the **discard technique**.

  ```
  (?:'?[a-z]){5,}|((?:'?[a-z]){4}'?)
  ```

  You use the alternation operator in context placing what you want to exclude on the left, ( *saying throw this away, it's garbage* ) and place what you want to match in a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) on the right side.

Comment: Works great and I used your regex explainer to edit of you don't mind.  If you don't like it please revert back. The use of `(?i)` is my first encounter.  Very nice.

Comment: Doesn't it fail for `This Jon's dogs' 'bout there in word re'y.` ?

Comment: I think this site missed one and you have written it down: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spells_in_Harry_Potter  Not an easy task at all.  I feel less bad about not being able to get it and this is a valuable learning experience.  Thank you.

Comment: @hwnd this is a very smart answer, it took me many discard patterns to achieve the same, you rock man.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?i)(?<![a-z'])(?:'?[a-z]){4}'?(?![a-z'])
```

Comment: however it doesn't allow `'bout`

Comment: @hex494D49: probably because `Mike's` has five letters.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the opposite :) It matches, and it shouldn't I guess.

Comment: @hex494D49: to be more exact, it matches only `Mike` and stops before `'s` due to the word boundary.

Comment: I'll add `Mike's` as this seems to be a corner case that should be addressed.

Comment: I see that, but it shouldn't since it's one word; but it also fails on `dogs'` and `'bout` since it doesn't capture the apostrophe. Reading the question, it should capture it but not count. Anyhow, good try :)

Comment: @hex494D49: yes I know for the requirements, but I will not go further since I don't see what is the final goal of this.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong :) I'm just a random reviewer this time since I gave up after seeing that my try is also failing on `Mike's` and so...

Comment: +1 This is the straightforward solution.  If the regexp should catch words with multiple ' the ? in the `'?` needs to be *.  Ie for "a''sdf"

Comment: +1 Ha, worked this problem for fun and came up with something nearly identical. :) `(?<!['a-z])(?:'?[a-z]'?){4}(?!['a-z])` (case-insensitive) That's an honor for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the **discard technique** and use a regex like this:

```
\b\w{0,2}\b(?:'\w)?|\b\w{3}(?!')\b|\b\w{5,}\b|('?\b\w+\b'?\w?)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/iW2wB7/4)**

[image]

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-4]   `This`
MATCH 2
1.  [5-10]  `Jon's`
MATCH 3
1.  [11-16] `dogs'`
MATCH 4
1.  [17-22] `'bout`
MATCH 5
1.  [32-36] `word`
```

For R it is needed to be escaped the special characters.

As you can see in the regex pattern you can use whatever you don't want at the left side of the pattern and leaving what you really want inside the capturing group at the rightest side. The idea behind the discard technique is:

```
discard this|don't want this|still don't care this|(Oh yeah! I grab this)
```

**THANKS** to **EdConttrell** and **johnwait** for helping me to improve the answer.

Comment: Your original answer just matches any word containing an apostrophe. Now, it explicitly matches 5-letter words, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @EdCottrell thanks to point that, but I had answered the question prior to be edited. I added an Update

Comment: `\b\w{5,}\b` is still incorrect, as is `\b\w{0,2}\b`. In your demo, it's matching the 2- and 5-letter words. OP doesn't mention wanting to extract those; just the 4-letter words.

Comment: @EdCottrell I think you are misunderstanding the regex. I'm using the discard technique for first two patterns and I'm grabbing the latest one. As you can see the match information it is showing exactly what OP wants.

Comment: @EdCottrell I think the answer implies to filter for capturing groups only.

Comment: @Fede I see your point. That's clever, but it still won't work. Try adding a 3-letter word like `the` somewhere in the string; your regex will match it.

Comment: @EdCottrell you are greedy like regex! :) It's ok, I've just added a discard pattern for what you mean. Do you like it now? (I'm kindly teasing you)

Comment: @johnwait this can be easily solved. I'll update the answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm quite impressed my friend but yours also fails on `Mike's` Check it out :) [http://regex101.com/r/iW2wB7/5](http://regex101.com/r/iW2wB7/5)

Comment: @hex494D49 Thanks for point that, this is simple it's a matter of add the discard pattern and that'd solve the problem. You can check it here http://regex101.com/r/iW2wB7/6. Btw, since this question has marked as resolved so I haven't updated it anymore since has no sense :) anyway, thanks for help me improving it.

Answer (score 5):

**EDITED** twice: (thanks [hex494D49](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310701/hex494d49)):

`(?i)(?<=\W|^)(?<!')'*(?:\w{4}|\w'*\w{3}|\w{2}'*\w{2}|\w{3}'*\w|\w{2}'*\w'*\w|\w'*\w{2}'*\w|\w'*\w'*\w{2}|\w'*\w'*\w'*\w)'*(?!')(?=\W|$)`

Better go for every possible cases...

**But**, title of question states :

```
grab n letter words don't count apostrophes regex
```

So I would *not* recommend my solution.

Comment: Heavy duty but appears to work unless someone can think of a corner case.

Comment: Don't know much about R though... Wonder if it supports lookbehind/lookaheads?

Comment: **Please**, stop up-voting my answer!

Answer (score 4):

Another solution that I think may be slightly clearer / more concise:

#### Regex

```
(?<![\w'])(?:'?\w'?){4}(?![\w'])
```

#### Explanation

```
(?<![\w'])
```

This is a Negative Lookbehind Assertion: it checks that the match is not preceded by the `'` char or a word char (`\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z]`).

```
(?:'?\w'?){4}
```

This matches any word char, optionally preceded/succeeded by a `'`. The `(?: ... )` makes the group non-capturing.

```
(?![\w'])
```

This is a Negative Lookahead assertion, ensuring that the group is not followed by another apostrophe or letter char.

The purpose of the first and last terms is to ensure that the 4 matches by the middle group are not surrounded by more characters: i.e. the word only has 4 letters.

They are more or less equivalent to a `\b` word boundary detection, except that they count an apostrophe as part of a word which `\b` does not.

#### Issues

The regex won't match strings that start or end with double apostrophes, `''`. I don't think this is a huge loss.

#### Example

See this link on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/yK8bZ7/1).

Comment: I just noticed that this is pretty similar to @Casimir et Hippolyte 's answer. However I'll leave it here since it has more explanation.

Comment: This is concise and on 2000 vectors performs identically to hwnd's.  +1